# Discrepancy in `scan` and `match` behavior for different Ruby versions

Tags: ruby, regex, match

### Background

This question is in regards to the behavior of the `String#scan` and `String#match` method in Ruby.  I am using a recursive regular expression which is supposed to match a balanced pair of braces.  You can see this regular expression `/(\((?:[^\(\)]*\g<0>*)*\))/` in action at: https://regex101.com/r/Q1lOC8/1.  There it displays the expected behavior:  match top level sets of brackets that have balanced sets of nested brackets.  Some sample code illustrating the problem is as follows:

```
➜  cat test.rb                                                                          
s = "1+(x*(3-4)+5)-1"
r = /(\((?:[^\(\)]*\g<0>*)*\))/
puts s.match(r).inspect
puts s.scan(r).inspect
```

### Problem

I get different results when running the above sample code in ruby-2.3.3 and ruby-2.4.1:

```
➜  docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app ruby:2.3.3-alpine ruby test.rb
#<MatchData "(x*(3-4)+5)" 1:")">
[[")"]]
➜  docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app ruby:2.4.1-alpine ruby test.rb
#<MatchData "(x*(3-4)+5)" 1:"(x*(3-4)+5)">
[["(x*(3-4)+5)"]]
```

The case in ruby-2.4.1 is what I was expecting.  `match` is correctly matching to the same outer set of parentheses in both cases, `(x*(3-4)+5)`, but in ruby-2.3.3 the first group match for some reason is just `")"`.  If I change the regular expression to `/(\(.*\))/`, then the behavior is the same for both versions (same as 2.4.1 above), but it no longer will ensure nested braces are balanced.

What is the true expected behavior of `match` in this case?

Comment: From what I understand, recursion takes the whole regex pattern here (as you use `\g<0>`) and the group 1 is constantly re-written from iteration to iteration. You may use `r = /(\((?:[^\(\)]*\g<1>*)*\))/` in Ruby 2.3 to ensure you get the whole matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I should note that what works at regex101.com does not have to work anywhere: any regex written with the help of an online regex tester *must* be tested in the target environment. You tested with the PCRE option, and it worked, because PCRE is a different library than Onigmo used in Ruby.

Now, the problem seems to be how Onigmo regex engine handles recursion in 2.3.3: the `\g<0>` construct recurses the whole pattern (0th group), and the outer capturing parentheses (Group 1) are also repeated (while its ID is kept the same), effectively creating a *repeated capturing group*. The values in such groups are re-written at each iteration, and that is why you get `)` in the end.

The work around is to recurse  Group 1 subpattern to keep Group 1 value in full without re-writing its value upon each iteration (since a capturing group is defined in the pattern, `String#scan` only returns the *capture(s)*).

Use

```
r = /(\((?:[^\(\)]*\g<1>*)*\))/
                      ^
```